# Symmetric power $Sym^{n} End(V)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider $V$ a finite dimensional vector space. How can I see that
$$\{X^{\otimes n} : X \in End(V) \}$$

span $Sym^{n}End(V)$?

Comment: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/four-flavors-of-schur-weyl-duality/ Lemma 2 is what you are looking for.

Comment: NB the blog post restricts to vector spaces over fields of characteristic $0$. I didn't check whether that restriction can be lifted for this result.